# VueJS $store.dispatch send multiple parameters

Tags: vuejs2

I want to pass a second parameter to a dispatch call:

```
 this.$store.dispatch(
          'testAction',
          this.employee.employeeId,
          departmentId
          ));
```

My store Action is the following:

```
async testAction({ dispatch, commit },  employeeId, departmentId) {
    console.log(departmentId);

    return 'Employee Tested';
  },
```

When I see console log for departmentId i get "undefined".

Any clue on how to pass multiple parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Basically, you can't send multiple parameters. You need to dispatch with a `payload` object containing your parameters.