# Vuejs element-ui form not updating model

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

My model is not updating when I enter in any values and when I dispatch to my store, it tells me the object "item" is undefined. Can someone help me out here? I feel like the syntax is correct. This is the actual SFC i am using

```html
<template>
    <el-form :model="item" ref="item" label-width="120px">
        <el-form-item label="Name" required>
            <el-input v-model="item.name" autocomplete="off"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item label="Description">
            <el-input v-model="item.description"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
            <el-button type="primary" @click='submitForm'>Submit</el-button>
            <el-button @click='clearForm'>Clear</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'itemForm',
        data () {
            return {
                item: {
                    name: '',
                    description:''
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm() {
                this.$store.dispatch('addItem', this.item)
            },
            clearForm() {
                console.log("CLEAR")
                this.$refs['item'].resetFields()
            }

        },
        watch: {
            item: function() {
                console.log(this.item)
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

I have made a usable Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zheactj9/1/

Comment: It is actually `$store` that is undefined. Did you register your store (Vuex) properly? Can you please provide the code for it?

Comment: Sorry did not include store code. However, if you remove store code, you would still notice that the item object does not change when you enter values into the form.

Comment: It does change on my end, have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/0jfk6es2/

Comment: You are right it does seem to change. I think the issue is related to my vuex code.

Comment: I just found the issue. I was sending multiple parameters from my dispatcher which is not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958909/vuejs-store-dispatch-send-multiple-parameters

Comment: You can send multiple parameters as payload. I will edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: However, do you know why my 'clear' button doesn't work?

Comment: I am guessing that there is an issue with `$refs` and `element-ui` in the example but have a look at my answer for a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example of how you would use Vuex [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-vuex-example-efpjx?file=/components/Hello.vue).

Have a look, I used pretty much the same code as yours.

---

Sending multiple parameters as payload:

```
submitForm() {
  this.$store.dispatch("addItem", {
    item1: this.item,
    item2: this.item,
    item3: this.item
  });
}
```

Example of a store action:

```
actions: {
  addItem: function(store, payload) {
    console.log(payload);
  }
}
```

To reset your form you could simply do:

```
clearForm() {
   this.item.name = ''
   this.item.description = ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created an example with `Vuex` store which updates with action and mutation and a getter and computed property which provide the new record. Example:

```js
ELEMENT.locale(ELEMENT.lang.ja)

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    item: {
      name: '',
      description:''
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ITEM(state, payload) {
      // mutate state
      state.item = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addItem ({ commit },payload) {
      commit('ADD_ITEM', payload)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    itemData: state => {
      return state.item
    }
  }
})

var Main = {
    data () {
      return {
          item: {
              name: '',
              description:''
          }
      }
    },
    store,
    methods: {
        submitForm() {
            this.$store.dispatch('addItem', this.item)
        },
        clearForm() {
            console.log("CLEAR")
            this.$refs['item'].resetFields()
        }

    },
    computed: {
     getItemData() {
        return this.$store.getters.itemData
     }
    },
    watch: {
        item: function() {
            console.log(this.item)
        }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <el-form :model="item" ref="item" label-width="120px">
          <el-form-item label="Name" required>
              <el-input v-model="item.name" autocomplete="off"></el-input>
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item label="Description">
              <el-input v-model="item.description"></el-input>
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item>
              <el-button type="primary" @click='submitForm'>Submit</el-button>
              <el-button @click='clearForm'>Clear</el-button>
          </el-form-item>
      </el-form>

  <div class="store-item">
  Store Item Data -> Name: {{ getItemData.name }} and Descruiption: {{ getItemData.description }}
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.3/lib/index.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/umd/locale/ja.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.2.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gwL275hk/2/

I hope this helps. I can explain in more details if you need, just ask.